# making a selection from a dropdown list without a submit button and auto refreshes the data

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get a value from a dropdown list and the then display the data from a xml I am supposed to use php to retrieve the data from the xml like this:

[image]

here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<People>
   <Person>
      <name>Ahmet</name>
      <surname>Guler</surname>
      <age>37</age>
      <gender>M</gender>
      <phone>111-111-1111</phone>
   </Person>
   <Person>
      <name>Tom</name>
      <surname>Sawyer</surname>
      <age>57</age>
      <gender>M</gender>
      <phone>222-222-2222</phone>
   </Person>
   <Person>
      <name>Sue</name>
      <surname>Myers</surname>
      <age>18</age>
      <gender>F</gender>
      <phone>333-333-3333</phone>
   </Person>
</People>
```

here is my php of where I made the drop down:

```
<form method="get">

            <select name='person'>
                <?php
                $xml = simplexml_load_file('a.xml');
                echo "<option value=''>Select an option:</option>";
                foreach ($xml->Person as $person) {
                    echo "<option value='" . $person->name . "'>" . $person->name . "</option>";
                } ?>
            </select> <br>


        </form>
```

I need to achieve this functionality without a submit button and it should auto refresh the data when a different person is selected.

Comment: Please use ajax

Comment: see this https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_xml.asp

Answer (score 2):

Ajax is one way to solve this as suggested by *Ken Lee* but in this case it would mean that every time you change the select, you need to perform and ajax call, which is not performing and causes additional traffic to the server.

Instead, you can use `data` attributes to store all the info of the `people` xml directly in the `<option>` of your select and then simply read them with `javascript`.

### 1. Populate `data` attribute in the options

The first edit you need to make is to add all the info of each `person` in each option. You can either create one `data` attribute for each property (so you would have 5 properties: name, surname etc...) or you can store the whole object as a `JSON`. The latter is what I chose in the example below:

```
foreach ($xml->Person as $person) {
    echo '<option value="'.$person->name.'" data-info="'.htmlentities(json_encode($person)).'">'.$person->name.'</option>';
}
```

`htmlentities` is important not to break the HTML attributes quotes, and `json_encode` transforms the object into a JSON string that can then be parsed by the Javascript.

### 2. Read and parse the JSON when the select changes

Start an `onchange` event to listen for changes to the select. When you have an option selected that is not the default one, then you can parse the JSON from the data attribute.

```
document.getElementsByName("person")[0].onchange = function(){
    if(this.value) {
        var info = JSON.parse(this.options[this.selectedIndex].dataset.info)
        console.log(info)
    }
}
```

If you run this, the code will show in your JS console the `person` information you had previously stored.

`this.options[this.selectedIndex]` contains the option that you currently selected

`dataset.info` is the way to access the JSON string from the data attribute we set at the previous step

`JSON.parse(` reconverts the string into an object that you can use

### 3. Populate the results

Instead of the `console.log` you can now use the `var info` to populate the information on the page as per your example.

```
document.getElementById("fname").innerText = info.name
```

And repeat for all the attributes. Of course you need to prepare the HTML before for cleanliness of code, so for example

```
<strong>Fname=</strong> <span id="fname"></span><br />
```

### 4. Full Working Code

```
<form method="get">

    <select name='person'>
        <?php
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('a.xml');
        echo "<option value=''>Select an option:</option>";
        foreach ($xml->Person as $person) {
            echo '<option value="'.$person->name.'" data-info="'.htmlentities(json_encode($person)).'">'.$person->name.'</option>';
        } ?>
    </select> <br>

    <div id="personinfo" style="display: none;">
        <strong>Fname=</strong> <span id="fname"></span><br />
        <strong>Sname=</strong> <span id="sname"></span><br />
        <strong>Age=</strong> <span id="age"></span><br />
        <strong>Gender=</strong> <span id="gender"></span><br />
        <strong>Phone=</strong> <span id="phone"></span>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.getElementsByName("person")[0].onchange = function(){
            if(this.value) {
                var info = JSON.parse(this.options[this.selectedIndex].dataset.info)
                document.getElementById("fname").innerText = info.name
                document.getElementById("sname").innerText = info.surname
                document.getElementById("age").innerText = info.age
                document.getElementById("gender").innerText = info.gender
                document.getElementById("phone").innerText = info.phone
                document.getElementById("personinfo").style.display = "block"
            } else {
                document.getElementById("personinfo").style.display = "none"
            }
        };
    </script>

</form>
```